# How to setup host and path rules in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I configured my load balancer to redirect traffic using the URL in 2 servers, newserver and oldserver. My Host and Paths rules looks like

*.   /*   newbackend
*.  /2016 newbackend
*.  /2015 oldbackend

The balancing mode is utilization 80%.

When I try to browse my site I can go to the newbackend, butmy oldbackend is not working is looking for the folder in my new server. It looks like the first rule is applying for all my traffic.

Comment: I added my naked domain and my full domain in the load balancer setting and it still working :)

Comment: From your comment it seems like you have resolved the issue. If so, please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The following setup worked for me. The complete content based LB guide can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example).

[image]